# After effects Timeline display: frames into milliseconds

Tags: video, after-effects

I'd like to change frames into milliseconds in the timeline.

Right one, it displays seconds, and frames in between. But since, I have to work on a music video, i'd like it to be milliseconds inbetween (base 100).

How to do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a workaround:

Create a left aligned text layer - type a zero. Format to the size and colour of your choice.
Twirl down this layer, twirl down text, ALT click the stopwatch on the Source text property. In the expression field that opens in the timeline, replace the text with:

Math.round(time*1000)+" ms"

click out of the text field into a blank area of the timeline.

The text will now show the time of the current frame in milliseconds.